# Twitter widget width not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-timeline

I have tried everything using css that i can think of , and set with in the embed , but i cant not get it to width more then 500px

https://jsfiddle.net/9d73rhvj/

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-widget-id="694535126655635456" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev" width="1300" height="750">Tweets by @PTDcommish</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

CSS i've tried

```
#twitter-widget-0 { 
      width: 100% !important; 
}

.twitter-timeline-rendered { 
      width: 100% !important; 
}

iframe[id^='twitter-widget-']{ 
      width:100%;
}

.twitter-timeline {
    width: 100% !important; 
}
```

Comment: it's a widget, not a page; i think that's how twitter wants it. at any rate, you don't control the style, twitter does; your CSS has no effect on xdomain pages.

Comment: Its pulling the content in via an iframe.  Your CSS wont be able to affect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter has set a maximum width for embedded timelines to 520px, which my guess is as why your solutions aren't working.

From their docs ([link](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines)):

> **Dimensions**
>
> An embedded timeline list template automatically adjusts to
>   the width of its parent element with a minimum width of 180 pixels and
>   a maximum width of 520 pixels.